# Kali screen flickers

Tags: drivers, kali-linux, nvidia

I have a new Laptop "MSI GP72" with:

- **GeForce GTX 950M** Graphic Card
- **Ubuntu 16.04 && Kali 2016.2** as operating systems in dual boot mode...

In Unbuntu 16.04 everything works fine... 
but in Kali 2016.2 the Screen flickers...

When I don't move my Mouse it flickers slower but when I move my Mouse the flicker get's so fast that you mean the screen works but if you really look closely at the window then you can see it quite there...

For example, when I run the "CPU Overview" the screen flickers really fast because there is some action in this window... when I close it the screen starts to flicker again...

I have already tried this:

[Kali nvidia installation](http://de.docs.kali.org/general-use-de/installation-des-nvidia-treibers-fuer-kali)

the flollowing code is used:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
apt-get install nvidia-kernel-dkms

sed 's/quiet/quiet nouveau.modeset=0/g' -i /etc/default/grub
update-grub
reboot
```

But when I done this an reboot I get the error you can see in the Image...
[image: Error screen]

I don't know what I can do...
I tried every tutorial I found in the internet but nothing helps...

Maybe you had the same problem...

Thanks for answers... and sorry for my english :)

P.S.: When I run Kali in VM in Ubunut 16.04 it works perfect...

Comment: Fill a bugreport. http://docs.kali.org/community/submitting-issues-kali-bug-tracker

Comment: Do you have a idea after that??

Comment: Waiting for fixed packages. Kali is a rolling distro based on testing. Small bugs are normal, and must be reported. This is the method of developing a distro.

Comment: Do you thing it's better to download an other version (stable)??

Comment: Kali wasn't designed for use it on primary pc. It's goal is to run on a testmachine, and i think they're not focusing on to be compatible with modern videocard. And nvidia also doesn't focus on support the rolling kali.
I recommend Debian Stable (you can still install any stuff what kali has already preinstalled): http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/current/amd64/iso-cd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install bumblebee

When you see your 'oops'
Ctrl+alt+f2 or f3 or f4
Login

```
apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia
```

reboot

normally this is what you need

Comment: I will try this

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: @Developer66 did the command output any errors, or did it complete successfully?